# Using Excel VBA to insert Vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm having trouble using VBA to insert a vlookup formula in a column. I get a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". I suspect this could be an issue with the "double-quotes" thing. I've done some research on this, but still can't manage to wrap my head around when the double quotes are needed, and when they are not. Also, I'm using a dynamic date variable (TodaysDate), a string determined by =Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"). Below is the code line that's not working:

```
Range("Y2:Y" & RowCount).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(X2,""'[PHO """ & TodaysDate & """.xlsx]Detail'!$C:$D""),1,FALSE)),""Yes"",""No"")"
```

Comment: Print the string you are trying to put in the fomula in the debug window.  Is it what you want?  Is the name of the workbook right?

Comment: And how do I use the debug window? Sorry, I'm a relative noob.

Comment: Make sure the immediate window is open (Ctrl-G) then add `Debug.Print "=IF(..."` before the line that throws the error.  It will print out in the immediate window

Comment: i think you have one extra `)` after `!$C:$D""),1,FALSE`. maybe i am wrong :)

Comment: Dubison, you were right. You were right about the extra parenthesis. Tell your sister, you were right.....  `"=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(X2,'[PHO " & TodaysDate & ".xlsx]Detail'!$C:$D,1,FALSE)),""No"",""Yes"")"`

Answer (score 0):

Having worked on the same thing this past week I found it was easier to assign the file name (and in my case location) to a variable and place that into the vlookup instead of putting it all inside. For example, I did the following and got past this hurdle.

```
filename1 = "C:\Users\me\Documents\Custom Office Templates\DataValidation.xlsx" & "Sheet1'!$A:$C"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PipelineData").Range("I2:I" & lrow) = "=VLOOKUP(trim(A2),'" & filename1 & " ,2,FALSE)"
```

so yours might be

```
 filename = "Pho" & TodaysDate & ".xlsx" & "Detail'!$C$D"
 Range("Y2:Y" & RowCount).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(X2,'" & filename & "),1,FALSE)),""Yes"",""No"")"
```

Dont' know if this counts as an answer but it might help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mr. Bungle. I'll use that in the future.